# How do I get a truly unique video id for a Facebook video using the Graph Api

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, video

I am trying to get a list of videos from a Facebook page, and my issue is that I am retrieving all the ids from the page/videos endpoint, but it appears to return a post id not the unique video id, as I have several video ids with the exact same meta data and video insights. the only difference is the permalink-url and the created at time.

```
let url = /${params.facebookid}/videos ? type = uploaded & since = $ {
  since
} & un‌​ til = $ {
  until
} & limit = 2‌​ 000;
var response = await FB.api(url, {
  fields: ['id']
});
```

Since Facebook has a mechanism for linking all these cross-posted video ids to the same insight data then they must have a truly unique id.

Any help solving this id issue would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Please post your code so we can have a look why you are not getting a unique id.

Comment: let url = `/${params.facebookid}/videos?type=uploaded&since=${since}&until=${until}&limit=2000`;
            var response = await FB.api(url, {fields:['id']});

Comment: Did you make any progress on this @ChrisBanks ?